# How to acquire an ArcGIS access token with Windows Authentication (single sign on)

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-rest-api, authentication

Consider the following scenario:

1. The end user is running an in-house build Windows desktop client that uses the ArcgGIS WPF library for rendering ArcGIS maps.
2. The end user is authenticated via Windows authentication.
3. Now I want the client to acquire an access token for the REST services *without* prompting the end user for his/her username/password. That is, given that the end user is already logged in via Windows AD, the client should be able to acquire an access token with NTLM/Kerberos or what ever it is Windows authentication is using.
4. The acquired token is then send to an in-house web service which will then access the ArcGIS REST services with the token and thus impersonating the end user without knowing either username or password (this web service is *not* part of the Windows domain).

Is that possible? How?

The server is "ArcGIS REST API for 10.1 SP1".

I am the client/server programmer - not the ArcGIS administrator :-)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is not possible. ArcGIS can authenticate by Windows Authentication OR token authentication - but not both at the same time. So there is no way to obtain a token using Windows Authentication.